# Using awk to get next fields

Tags: awk, grep

I have this input file (space is the separator for the two elements in the line otherwise there is just one element)

```
a:1
a:1 123
b:2 345 
c:3 456 
d:4 
d:4 456
..
..
```

I am interested in the output to be

```
a:1 123
d:4 456
```

i.e lines which have the preceding field to have just one field.

Comment: what if you have two (or more) consecutive lines with just one field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 { if (NF == 1) { getline; print; next; } }
```

Comment: or just:  NF == 1 {getline; print}

Comment: I'll never get used to the conditional form in AWK :)

Comment: It's actually pretty simple:  pattern {action} pattern {action} ... pairs.  If pattern matches perform the action.  If pattern is omitted, always perform the action.  If action is omitted, the default action is to print the current line.